# textboxfor not returning value on submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html.textboxfor

I'm working in asp.net mvc 4. I have a login model with 2 required fields: email and password. I'm using @Html.TextboxFor to get the correct value back. This works for my password, but I can't seem to get it working for the account.

Here's my code:

.cshtml

```
@model IntraNoviUserLoginModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Home"))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Password, new { id = "password", type = "password" })
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(IntraNoviUserLoginModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //Code
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public class IntraNoviUserLoginModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }    
}
```

I have not set the email textbox to enabled=false. It should remain enabled the entire time.

I hope we can figure this out together

Comment: should public class model be public class IntraNoviUserLoginModel?

Comment: I thought I changed every name to model, but it seems I forgot it there. Since we use long names, I changed them to model in the example. I'll edit it out right now. I'm using the correct model in my code.

Comment: and @model model to pair it up

Comment: @dougajmcdonald I don't really understand what you mean.

Comment: previously you had @Model model in your view file. If you're changing the public class model, then the view should match. Your amended post reflects this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by using EditorFor instead of TextboxFor. I don't know why it suddenly works, maybe somebody can enlighten me in the comments?

Comment: I know this is 2 years late, but I'm experiencing this exact issue now... EditorFor doesn't let you assign classes easily but TextBoxFor isn't returning values. So I'm at a loss!